# How to use different indices for tex coords array and vertex array using glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

I've been trying to use `glDrawElements` in my tile-based 2D OpenGL game. However when I draw the tiles, the tex coords may be different for different faces at the same vertex: For example, here the texcoords will be different for the 2 quads at the common vertex:

```
___|
___|___
   |___
   |___
```

The problem is that `glDrawElements` takes only one index array and so it appears that I can only use one tex coord per vertex. Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** You don't. You instead break your vertices down into unique vertices, so that you can have a single index list for every attribute. If you have multiple index lists, you need to walk that list of indices, replicating attribute data (positions, texture coordinates, etc) for any set of indices that is not repeated.

**Long answer:** You *shouldn't*.

With modern hardware capabilities techniques ([buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) in OpenGL 3.x and/or [shader image load/store](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/shader_image_load_store.txt) in 4.x), you can subvert the attribute pipeline entirely and load data arbitrarily from buffer objects. However, you should not expect this to be nearly as fast as just doing things the right way.

Unless you have some well-defined *need* to do it this way (and I don't just mean your model format provides data like this), you're better off doing things properly. Remember: this is something *every* graphics application that uses arrays in rendering has done for the last decade and a half. You won't be missing out on any special hardware features or anything.

Comment: So you mean don't bother using glDrawElements and instead use the conventional approach of repeating vertices once per face?

Comment: No. You make all your attributes use a _single_ index array. This will involve replicating some of your vertex data.

Comment: You'd think that all that duplicate vertex data would be an extraordinary waste of memory. For a model I'm loading I have 2084 unique vertex positions and 4019 unique vertex normals. The number of (OpenGL-considered) unique vertices ends up being 12492, meaning it takes ~4x as much memory to store the vertex data using a single index. It sounds like a MASSIVE increase relatively, but in real terms the vertex data size has only increased from 69KB to 285KB. I suspect this is the reason why the API has never bothered to support multiple vertex attribute array indexes.